# How to add circle image in ET Text in OneEngine theme for WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am using OneEngine theme on Wordpress to create an About Me section. I want to create a similar part in my website.

[image: Desired appearance]

So far I have achieved this. 
[image: Appearance right now]

Using the code:

```
<span><div id="about" class="row">
<span class="col-md-6">
<div class="img-circle">
<img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200" />
</div>
</span>
<span class="col-md-6">
<p>Hello :) Testing. </p> </span>
</div> </span>
```

I am unable to make the image appear as a circle like above. I have tried adding CSS in ET Text and using `<div class="img-circle">` but that does not work.

Comment: Please post a demo of the code or give your page URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `img-circle` on the `img` tag and not on the parent element `div`. Remember to use equal width and height image for circular images to avoid distortion.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="image">
  <img class="img-circle" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following code into your style.css

```
.img-circle img {
border-radius: 50%;
border: 2px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `img-circle` class to the `img` tag, not the `div` tag. OR, define the class like:

```
.img-circle > img {
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```